# How to loop over tags in XML file using python

Tags: python, xpath, lxml

My XML file structure is:

```
<tp:Package xml:lang='en-US' xmlns:tp='http://myorg.org/2016/mypackage'>
    <tp:identifier>http://www.myweb.com/</tp:identifier>
    <tp:name>MyName</tp:name>
    <tp:description xml:lang='en-US'>My Description</tp:description>
    <tp:version>2020-01-01</tp:version>
    <tp:license href='http://www.myweb.com/terms/TermsConditions.html' name='Terms and Conditions' />
    <tp:publisher>MyPublisher</tp:publisher>
    <tp:publisherURL>http://www.mypublisherurl.com/</tp:publisherURL>
    <tp:publisherCountry>US</tp:publisherCountry>
    <tp:publicationDate>2020-01-01</tp:publicationDate>
    <tp:entryPoints>
        <tp:entryPoint>
            <tp:name>Form A</tp:name>
            <tp:description>This is Form A.</tp:description>
            <tp:version>v313</tp:version>
            <tp:entryPointDocument href='http://www.myweb.com/myfile.xsd' />
            <tp:formType>1</tp:formType>
        </tp:entryPoint>
        <tp:entryPoint>
            <tp:name>Form B</tp:name>
            <tp:description>This is Form B.</tp:description>
            <tp:version>v313</tp:version>
            <tp:entryPointDocument href='http://www.myweb.com/myfile.xsd' />
            <tp:formType>2</tp:formType>
        </tp:entryPoint>   
    </tp:entryPoints>
</tp:Package>
```

How Do I read this file using etree and loop over each  tag and print the values of element **tp:name, tp:description, tp:version, tp:entryPointDocument, tp:formType**

Following is my partial python code:

```
from lxml import etree
tree = etree.parse(xmlfilepath)
root = tree.getroot()
for elt in root.xpath("//tp:entryPoints", namespaces={'tp': 'http://myorg.org/2016/mypackage'}):
    print(elt)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
package = """your xml above"""    
from lxml import etree    
tree = etree.fromstring(package)

for elt in tree.xpath("//tp:entryPoints//*", namespaces={'tp': 'http://myorg.org/2016/mypackage'}):
    print(elt.text)
```

Output:

```
Form A
This is Form A.
v313
None
1


Form B
This is Form B.
v313
None
2
```